# which argtypes for NetShareAdd

Tags: python, ironpython, pywin32

The win32 function NetShareDel takes three arguments, LPCWSTR LPCWSTR and DWORD.

So I use the following list for argtypes:

```
import ctypes as C

C.windll.Netapi32.NetShareDel.argtypes = [LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, c_int]
C.windll.Netapi32.NetShareDel.restype = c_int
    
C.windll.Netapi32.NetShareDel(server, shareName, 0)
```

That works fine, but I can't figure out what to use for NetShareAdd, especialle the byte array for NET_SHARE_INFO struct and the last byref(c_int) argument.

Here's the code:

```
def Share(server, shareName, dir):    
    info = SHARE_INFO_2()

    STYPE_DISKTREE = 0

    info.shi2_netname = shareName
    info.shi2_path = dir
    info.shi2_type = STYPE_DISKTREE
    info.shi2_remark = "Shared: " + time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H:%M")
    info.shi2_max_uses = -1
    info.shi2_passwd = ""
    info.shi2_current_uses = 0
    info.shi2_permissions = 0xFFFFFFFF
    
    i = c_int()

    bytearray = buffer(info)[:]
    
    windll.Netapi32.NetShareAdd.argtypes = [LPCWSTR, c_int, ????, ????]

    windll.Netapi32.NetShareAdd(server, 2, bytearray, C.byref(i))
```

What would be the correct argtypes list for NetShareAdd?

Comment: NET_API_STATUS NetShareAdd(
  _In_  LPWSTR  servername,
  _In_  DWORD   level,
  _In_  LPBYTE  buf,
  _Out_ LPDWORD parm_err
);

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525384(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I know the signature, but what to use for the third parameter. bytearray = buffer(info)[:] is the python code but how to pass that with what argtypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working finally

First the line

```
bytearray = buffer(info)[:]
```

was changed into byte pointer type

```
byteptr = C.POINTER(C.wintypes.BYTE)(info)
```

and then the argtypes and call will become POINTER(BYTE) too of course:

```
C.windll.Netapi32.NetShareAdd.argtypes = [LPCWSTR, c_int, C.POINTER(C.wintypes.BYTE), C.POINTER(c_int)]
C.windll.Netapi32.NetShareAdd.restype = c_int

windll.Netapi32.NetShareAdd(server, 2, byteptr, C.byref(i))
```