# Sharing directory on windows using Python3

Tags: winapi, python-3.6

Is there a package in Python3, which can check if a windows directory is shared? and also to share a windows directory?

I am aware of using 'net share' command, I would like to know if there are is a pythonic way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

For check and add, you could use [`NetShareCheck`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netsharecheck) and [`NetShareAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netshareadd).
And here is an [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121435/which-argtypes-for-netshareadd) to use netapi in python.

Or Use winapi [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfoa) with `SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES`, then check the `dwAttributes` flag for [`SFGAO_SHARE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/sfgao#SFGAO_SHARE).

You could create it with class [`Win32_Share`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-share) and its [`Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/create-method-in-class-win32-share) method

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
c.Win32_Share().Create(args)
```

Comment: From the text of the question: "which can check if a windows directory is shared?" How does this answer address that?